# How to check live stream is still alive use "ffprobe" command?

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, live, rtmp

I want to schedule a job script to check a live stream is still alive use "ffprobe" command. So that I can change database state for those steam already dead.

I tried the command:

```
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_streams rtmp://xxxx
```

but when the stream is not avaiable, the command will hang.
I tried add -timeout argument, but still cannot work properly.

Comment: Did you ever solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The `timeout` option seems to be for listen mode. I would try to run ffmpeg using the `timeout` command or use something similar for the framework/language your using.

So for example:

```
timeout 10s ffprobe -v quiet ...
```

And maybe even use `--kill-after`. And then look at the exit code to determinate what happened.